# Vanilla Maven 3.3.9 does not find Magnolia catalog for blossom archetype generation with message: "No catalog defined. Using internal catalog"

Tags: maven, magnolia, maven-archetype

The Magnolia CORE Docs for Version 5.5 requires for [Getting started with Blossom](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Getting+started+with+Blossom) an maven archetype generation based on their own [catalog repository](https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/groups/public/). I can see and enter that archetype-catalog.xml as it should be andy everything seems right there.

However if I try to generate it with the given command from the documentation

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/groups/public/
```

I don't get the list of the magnolia foreign repo, but from the fallback maven-archetype repo.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO]     ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO]     ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
`enter code here`[INFO] No catalog defined. Using internal catalog
[INFO] No archetype defined. Using maven-archetype-quickstart (org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.0)
Choose archetype:
1: internal -> org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-archetype (An     archetype which contains a sample archetype.)
2: internal -> org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-j2ee-simple (An archetype which contains a simplifed sample J2EE application.)
3: internal -> org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-plugin (An archetype which contains a sample Maven plugin.)
4: internal -> org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-plugin-site (An archetype which contains a sample Maven plugin site.
  This archetype can be layered upon an existing Maven plugin project.)
5: internal -> org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-portlet (An archetype which contains a sample JSR-268 Portlet.)
6: internal -> org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-profiles ()
7: internal -> org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart (An archetype which contains a sample Maven project.)
8: internal -> org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-site (An archetype which contains a sample Maven site which demonstrates
  some of the supported document types like APT, XDoc, and FML and demonstrates how
  to i18n your site. This archetype can be layered upon an existing Maven project.)
9: internal -> org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-site-simple (An archetype which contains a sample Maven site.)
10: internal -> org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp (An archetype which contains a sample Maven Webapp project.)
Choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive contains): 7:
```

As in the Tutorial the

```
1: https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/groups/public/ -> info.magnolia.maven.archetypes:magnolia-theme-archetype
2: ...
```

archetypes from the magnolia catalog should be proposed instead of the maven ones.

The line

```
[INFO] No catalog defined. Using internal catalog
```

additionally points to a wrong catalog definition.

I have not altered my maven as it's a pretty new installation and tried really multiple possible solutions to get it running as for one of my colleagues the archetype generation works, for all others it doesn't. Even if we removed its local repo it still worked afterwards. A downgrade to its maven version brought no solution as well.

Any ideas on how to get this running? Does it work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest to use the following for the time being which should do the trick for you.

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/groups/public/
```

Reason being is that Apache released a new version (3.0.0 that is) and breaks this functionality ([ARCHETYPE-519](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARCHETYPE-519)).

Comment: thanks a lot! seems like i've been looking for the issue everywhere but in that direction.

Comment: @Ducaz035 jira ticket for updating archetype/catalog and note in docu in the mean time? ;)

Comment: @jan Indeed that makes sense :)