# No archetype defined when doing mvn archetype:generate with URL for

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

I was trying to set archetypeCatalog to URL when doing mvn archetype:generate but always shown no catalog or artifact found.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=http://myfaces.apache.org
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
[INFO] No catalog defined. Using internal catalog
[INFO] No archetype defined. Using maven-archetype-quickstart (org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.0)
Choose archetype:
1: internal -> org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-archetype (An archetype which contains a sample archetype.)
2: internal -> org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-j2ee-simple (An archetype which contains a simplifed sample J2EE application.)
3: internal -> org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-plugin (An archetype which contains a sample Maven plugin.)
4: internal -> org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-plugin-site (An archetype which contains a sample Maven plugin site.
      This archetype can be layered upon an existing Maven plugin project.)
5: internal -> org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-portlet (An archetype which contains a sample JSR-268 Portlet.)
6: internal -> org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-profiles ()
7: internal -> org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart (An archetype which contains a sample Maven project.)
8: internal -> org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-site (An archetype which contains a sample Maven site which demonstrates
      some of the supported document types like APT, XDoc, and FML and demonstrates how
      to i18n your site. This archetype can be layered upon an existing Maven project.)
9: internal -> org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-site-simple (An archetype which contains a sample Maven site.)
10: internal -> org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp (An archetype which contains a sample Maven Webapp project.)
Choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive contains): 7:
```

According to Maven archetype guide I should be able to set archetypeCatalog as URL:

http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/examples/generate-alternative-catalog.html

Any hints or guide what I did wrong? Thanks!

Comment: In the example above, http://myfaces.apache.org/archetype-catalog.xml contains list of archetypes

Comment: Can do me a favour and try a version prior to 3.0.0 ? I assume you hit to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARCHETYPE-519.

Comment: Yes, I was able to resolve this by moving back to 2.4. Thanks for the tips @Ducaz035

Comment: in case anyone need example of how to use v2.4, here is it : http://stackoverflow.com/a/42252982/90101

Answer (score 1):

Looks like issue with latest Maven archetype plugin:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARCHETYPE-519

This is regression from previous release.

Turning back to 2.4 solve this issue.